# React Router redirect not triggered after Formik form is submitted

Tags: reactjs, react-router, formik

I have a formik form, when I click on the submit button, I want the user to be redirected to /. But it doesn't work, nothing happens. I don't think it is useful to past here the code of the component, here is just the React Router route.

```
<Route exact path = "/create" 
            element = {
            <DepenseForm   
              onSubmit = {(depense) => {  
                console.log("1"); 
                console.log("2"); this.createDepense(depense); 
                console.log("3"); redirect("/")
                console.log("4");}
              } 
            />}
        />
```

In the console, all numbers are printed 1,2,3,4,5. The createDepense method is also executed.

But the React Router redirect method is not :(

No error messages, no warning.

Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a running demo using https://codesandbox.io/?

Answer (score 0):

The [`redirect`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/fetch/redirect) utility function is only validly used from Data router `loader` and `action` functions. It can't be used in a React component. You should use the [`useNavigate`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-navigate) hook instead and use the `navigate` function in the callback handler to issue an imperative redirect.

Since it appears you are passing in a submit handler to the routed component the `useNavigate` hook will need to be called in the parent component.

Example:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  ...

  return (
    ...
    <Routes>
      ...
      <Route
        path="/create" 
        element={(
          <DepenseForm   
            onSubmit={(depense) => {  
              ...
              createDepense(depense); 
              ...
              navigate("/", { replace: true });
              ...
            }} 
          />
        )}
      />
      ...
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

If the parent component is still an older React class component for some reason then you'll need to create your own custom `withRouter` Higher Order Component to inject the `navigate` function as a prop. For more information on this see [What happened to withRouter? I need it!](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it)